# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ and $x_n$ has a subsequence such that $(-1)^k \cdot x_{n_k} \geq 0$. Then prove that $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tired to use the following fact that if a sequence converges to a limit then all of its other subsequences must converge to the same limit as well. Hence I tried to apply the definition of $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}=x$ and see if I could find something.

I first set $x$ to be positive and then tried to arrive at a contradiction from here , but could not !

Please show the correct working to arrive at the solution !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following two subsequences 
$$\{x_{n_{2k}}\} \qquad \text{ AND } \qquad \{x_{n_{2k+1}}\}.$$ 
Based on the condition given $(-1)^{2k}x_{n_{2k}} \to x$ and $(-1)^{2k+1}x_{n_{2k+1}} \to -x$.

Now use the fact that every subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent to the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The condition implies that $(x_n)$ contains infinitely many nonnegative and infinitely many nonpositive terms.